# CSS: Span color when adjacent input is selected

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to create a css rule that will allow the `fa-search` icon to change color only when the input field is selected:

```
<div class="field-icon-prepend">

    <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
    <input type="search" id="top-nav-search" name="s" placeholder="Search">

</div>
```

How would I create this rule?

Comment: can you move the icon after the input, not before? there's no previous sibling rule, but there is next.

Comment: CSS can't affect elements that come before a particular selector. So to do this in CSS, you would need to put the input before the span, and use `input:focus + .fa-search` to affect `.fa-search` when someone selects (or focuses) in the input field. To do it with your current markup, you'll need to use javascript.

Comment: You can use javascript, so when you will focus on your input search you execute `document.getElementById("idOfTheSpan").className += " cssOfColoredIcon";` to this class you can do it like this : `document.getElementById("idOfTheSpan").className =
   document.getElementById("idOfTheSpan").className.replace
      ( /(?:^|\s)cssOfColoredIcon(?!\S)/g , '' )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not quite possible, but this is close enough:

```css
.fa-search{
  float:left;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}

#top-nav-search:focus + .field-icon .fa-search{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="field-icon-prepend">

    
    <input type="search" id="top-nav-search" name="s" placeholder="Search">
    <span class="field-icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>

</div>
```